# C# String formatting with double quotes (") and string interpolation

Tags: c#, string, format, string-formatting

How can I properly display this string?

```
string exampleHTML = String.Format(@"
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family ""ITC-AVANT"";
  src: url(""https://www.example.com"");
}
body {
  margin: 0;    
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=""title"">
  <p>{0}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>", exampleVariable);
```

In the back-end I am not getting any error while debugging, but in the client side it says that error is coming from the server.
Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

My solution was to add double curly brackets where string interpolation is not needed. In the beginning I also added:

```
string exampleHTML = $@"<html></html";
```

Comment: Your quote escapes are fine, but you need to escape your curly braces where you don't want interpolation. `@font-face {` should be `@font-face {{`, etc.

Comment: Apparently, you don't have any way to access details from exceptions occurring on the server. That's a **much more important problem** than the brace escaping issue you are currently facing. Fix that one first, so you don't have to "guess" every time you get a "server error".